# rename multiple files with a specific word

Tags: rename

I know this question has been asked many times but I'm very new to using command line and couldn't figure it out I have multiple files with names like this

```
SRR10984718_dbGaP-26719.sra
SRR10984540_dbGaP-26719.sra
SRR10984788_dbGaP-26719.sra
```

I want to rename them as follows

```
SRR10984718.sra
SRR10984540.sra
SRR10984788.sra
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: What `OS` do you have /  run?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can user `renaem` or **perl** directly or a a little bit `shell` script.

Usually i use **Perl** directly .

```
$ ls -1
SRR10984540_dbGaP-26719.sra
SRR10984718_dbGaP-26719.sra
SRR10984788_dbGaP-26719.sra
$
# dry run
$ perl -le '($old=$_) && s/_dbGaP-26719//g && print for <*.sra>'
SRR10984540.sra
SRR10984718.sra
SRR10984788.sra
$
# rename
$ perl -le '($old=$_) && s/_dbGaP-26719//g && rename($old,$_) for <*.sra>'
$
# test 
$ !ls
ls -1
SRR10984540.sra
SRR10984718.sra
SRR10984788.sra
```

This part `s/_dbGaP-26719//g` is for matching and replacing with nothing. Change the desired pattern (e.g. `_dbGaP-26719`) accordingly.